# Is there a way to change the keyboard delay when switching virtual desktops in OSX?

Tags: keyboard, trackpad, desktop

I use OSX 10.14.6, and I use virtual desktops to organize tasks. Often, these tasks involve typing. I will set an app to fullscreen mode and switch between desktops with the trackpad on my Macbook Pro.

When I switch desktops, there is an animation delay, which is fine. However, it seems that application focus does not immediately switch. This means that the first few keystrokes after a swipe gesture are captured by the original app (that I'm moving away from), not the target app. An example for this is Terminal - I may be working with commands in Terminal in one desktop and working with program output, or a website, or some other task in the other. Keystrokes are not captured correctly after the swipe gesture.

Is there a way to change this behavior? Is there a PLIST that can be edited to ensure that there is no delay between application focus, even if there is an animation involved?

Thank you.

Comment: If you use Ctrl/[num] the transition is twice as fast & you can type immediately… however, you can't do that for fullscreen apps, only numbered Spaces.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not immediate. (I use the accessibility option to reduce animation.) The application focus seems to wait on the animation to complete.

Comment: I tested it empirically, otherwise I wouldn't have suggested it.